# In Eclipse Plugin, how can I make standard editor dirty?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, editor

I am trying to programatically make an Eclipse editor dirty.

I know that firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY) can do that, on my own editors.

But in this case I am using a standard editor.
Can I make any editors dirty (how?) - or does the editor need to support this?

I have a org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2.
From here I want to make the Editor dirty, when I get the partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference arg0) event.

I have tried to look through simalar questuions in here. But I am stuck.

Any hints?

Comment: Possibly you can find the `MPart` for the part using the `EPartService` and then call `setDirty(true)` but I don't know if that will work. This doesn't really seem like something you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I will take a look at EPartService.
The reason for this approach is, that under some circumstances, my plugin generates a file with a content, which I want to force the user to consider.
I don't want to bend the rules to much, so it might not be the best solution.

Comment: If you're generating content for a file already open in an editor, the editor is expected to handle that itself--as long as your write the contents using the IFile APIs and the resource events work their way through the workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a trick.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
try {
    EditorPart ep = (EditorPart) IDE.openEditor( page, iFile );
    IEditorInput input = ep.getEditorInput();
    IDocument doc = ((ITextEditor) ep).getDocumentProvider().getDocument(input);
    doc.set(doc.get());
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will leave the editor dirty.